# Data transfer between servers extremely slow

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I have an application running on a Live environment with a  Web Server which is running Windows Server 2008 R2 with a QuadCore Xeon processor with 8GB of ram and a Database Server with the same configuration but with an additional disk with 2TB of space. The database server runs SQL Server 2008 R2. The two machines are connected through a crossover connection.
The application processes large loads of data from .csv files located in the webserver and stores them to the database. The data transfer and the number of items being processed per minute is very low compared to our benchmark times, which were set on a staging environment with a Web Server and Database Server running only 4 gb of ram. The staging environment processed a single .csv file at the rate of 6000 items per minute. The same file processed in the live environment ran at the rate of 2500 per minute. The staging environment, however is not running through cross cables but is using a standard switch. Suggestions as to why there is a drop in performance are welcome.

Comment: does the live enviro have AV running where the staging didn't?  Also by default w2k8r2 runs in power saving mode which slows things down quite a bit.

Comment: Actually both live and staging environments had had AV removed and both environments are running  w2k8r2.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are not getting packet errors. Ensure that the auto configuration for the nics is working properly or hard code the values for speed, duplex, etc. This used to be a common problem, but has improved over the last decade with better nics and switches.

Comment: We set the network configuration from automatic to 100mbps Full Duplex. This time we tried to emulate it using the same network configuration as the staging, still no change. However, we tried transferring a standard file of around 20mb over the connection, it seemed to transfer just fine